# New elements vanish when function ends

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple form that allows the user to create a number of blank tables with a variable number of rows and columns. The code generates no errors, and briefly creates the new table elements, but when the function ends the tables vanish. What am I doing wrong?

```
function genTable(){
    var numRows = parseInt(document.getElementById("numRows").value); // Number of rows per table
    var numCols = parseInt(document.getElementById("numCols").value); // Number of columns per table
    var numTabs = parseInt(document.getElementById("numTabs").value); // number of tables

    var startDiv = document.getElementById("start");
    var oneCell = "<td class=\"cell\"></td>"; // HTML for a single cell
    var myHTML = ""; // An empty string to contain the tables

    for(i=0; i<numTabs; i++){
        myHTML += "<div><table class=\"linesTab\" id=\"winLine" + (i+1) + "\">";

        for(k=0; k<numRows; k++){
            myHTML += "<tr>";

            for(j=0; j<numCols; j++){
            myHTML += oneCell;
            }

            myHTML += "</tr>";
        }


        myHTML += "</table><br><span class=\"tabSpan\">" + (i+1) + "</span></div>";
    }

    startDiv.innerHTML= myHTML;

}
```

Comment: where's the code that calls getTable()? What is it doing after getTable() is called?

Comment: When you say it briefly creates them - do you mean on the screen? The tables aren't added to the DOM until the very last line of the function, so if you're seeing the tables on the screen and then they disappear shortly after, it means they're disappearing for some other reason. Are you using a button that could be causing the page to refresh? Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46477056/edit) your question to include the smallest snippet of HTML needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: We need more code/markup to begin to answer this question.

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a trigger built into a hyperlink or a form... so although your script runs, the browser navigates and refreshes the page.

If you have a click event, you need to stop the event from propagating.

Short example:

HTML

```
<div id="example">


</div>

<form>
    <input type="number" id="num" />
    <button id="clicker">
    Go
    </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('clicker').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = 'Content';
    // return false; // <-- without this (or an alternative) the form posts
}
```

Comment: This was the correct answer! I had the button inside of my <form> tag, so it was navigating to a new page with the form values in the URL. As soon as I placed the button outside of the form and changed the call from onclick="genTable()" to an event listener in the script section, my code worked perfectly.